# Service crashing due to RabbitMQ Not found exception

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp

Recently one of our services have started crashing intermittently, while it is running, with below errors -

Error on startup -

```
Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'avitas.nodedata' in vhost 'avitas': received 'topic' but current is 'fanout', class-id=40, method-id=10)
```

Error before crashing -

```
operation queue.declare caused a channel exception not_found: no queue 'queue' in vhost 'host'
```

Below are some details -
The service only has consumer configuration.
The service is running as a docker pod in kubernetes and is configured to autoscale.
The exchange type is fanout
The Queues are configured with 'auto-delete' and 'exclusive'
RabbitMQ version - 3.7.28
Erlang version - 22.3.4.7

Below is the consumer service configuration -

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    inputChannel:
      destination: exchange1
      contentType: application/data+proto

rabbit.bindings:
      inputChannel:
      consumer:
        exchangeType: fanout
```

Below is the producer service configuration -

```
# Spring cloud stream
spring.cloud.stream:
  bindings:
    outputChannel:
      destination: exchange1
      contentType: application/data+proto

rabbit.bindings:
      outputChannel:
       producer:
        exchangeType: fanout
```

We have also checked all other configurations, not really sure why the exchange type is going as 'topic' instead of fanout.

Comment: Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this behavior.

Comment: What type is avitas? You will find the type in Rabbit MQ console.